# How Can I Check and know how many websites/blogs are linking to my website.?

Tags: links

Can I know how many websites/Blogs are linking to my website? Is there any free tools? Can I use with google.com too?

Can I use also with google.com link:www.mysite.com ?

What is the different between Link:www.mysite.com and url:mysite.com ?

Answer (score 3):

A common tool used for this is [Yahoo Site Explorer](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com), almost all the tools that will give you this information use it's API.

One such tool is [Spyglass SEO](http://www.link-assistant.com/seo-spyglass/) for example, free to try, [download from CNET](http://download.cnet.com/SEO-SpyGlass-Enterprise/3000-18485_4-10631702.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to find inlinks; these are the best three that I'm aware of:

- Search for `link:yoursite.com` in Google, Bing and/or Yahoo. This is the quickest way to see links. In Yahoo will redirect you to their site explorer which is quite nice.
- Sign up for [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) where you can see links to your site and other goodness. Usually you will get more links here than through the `link:` query.
- [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/) tends to show the most relevant links. Basic list is free, however, you need to pay a lot of money to see more than the top 25.

Regarding your latter question, there is no `url:` search that I'm aware of. You are probably thinking of `site:`. The difference is `link:example.com` finds all pages linking to example.com, while `site:example.com` shows you all the pages on example.com (that the search engine has indexed).

Comment: He might be thinking of the `inurl` operator, which searches for the term specifically in the URL. Not useful for backlinks though.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some information on inbound links by logging into [Google Webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) and choosing "Your site on the web" > "Links to your site"

Answer (score 0):

MajesticSEO is what I use, if you verify your domain with them they will give you all the link data for your site for free.