# Is it possible to know impressions of other websites?

Tags: google-search-console, impressions

Google Webmasters's Dashboard gives you a big number which is called **impressions**, and  that I've seen in Google Analytics. By definition, it means the total number of times your site has been become eligible for SERPs.

I just don't have an idea how to interpret this number, and how much its increase or decrease mean to me, because I can't compare it with other websites.

I mean, if the impressions of say site `a.com` are 150,000, and the impressions of my site are 50,000, then maybe it implies that I need to triple my efforts to reach the impression rate of `a.com`. Yet, by seeing 50,000 impressions alone, I have no clue at all of how to interpret it.

Is there any service or other way to know about the impressions Google gives to other sites?

Comment: Note: I know you are asking about impressions in SERPs, not raw traffic. But the two correlate very strongly.

Comment: Everything is possible. However, I don't think there is any LEGAL way to do this. You could get a really rough estimate if you build on the answer pointed out by DisgruntedGoat

Comment: Well, this was not duplicate. I didn't ask about *traffic*. I asked about *impressions*. Just like I know how to compare my site with other sites using Alexa's ranking, I knew about traffic.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati Sorry about the question being closed, me and the other mods took another look at it and decided it should be reopened.

Comment: It's OK @Christofian. These things happen sometimes ;). Thanks for looking again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by impressions you mean how many times a site is listed in google, then all you need to do is search google for `site:sitename.com`. Above the search results, google will tell you how many pages it has indexed and that it can theoretically put in it's search results for that site. That can give you a *very rough* idea of how many serps that website shows up in.

You can also use [google trends](https://www.google.com/trends/?q=seo) to see how many people are searching for certain keywords, and then use that information to see how many people would search for queries related to that website, which would also give you a *very rough* idea of how many serps that website shows up in.

SEO ranking tools like pagerank could also help see how good a site's SEO is (that would help because sites with better SEO usually get in more page results). You could also look at h[ow many links a site has](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/4736/6901), with the idea being that the more links a site has, the more likely it will be that it does will in search results.

However, Google and other search engines (to the best of my knowledge) don't release data about how many times a website appears in search results to anybody other than the website owner.

Comment: Well, this only gives you the `x` where `x` is the number of pages indexed by Google (though, it's not accurate either). But impression means `y` where `y` is the total number of times these indexed pages can appear in SERPs. For example, you might have only one page, but that page might appear 3000 times in SERPs. On the other hand, by having 1000 page you might get only 100 result in SERPs. In this case, the first site has more impressions.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati edited, but I'm afraid that there isn't a service that can give you an exact number